# Why does this program not find the word 'error' in my text file?

Tags: perl, perl-io

```
open(LOG,"logfile.txt") or die "Unable to open $logfile:$!";
print "\n";
while(<$LOG>){
  print if /\berror\b/i;
}
close(LOG);
```

Comment: use strict. use strict. use strict.

Comment: use warnings; even more important than use strict

Comment: use 3-arg open and lexical file handles :)

Answer (score 10):

Your typo actually takes you one step closer to opening the file the right way -- namely, using the recommended 3-argument form of [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $log, '<', "logfile.txt") or die "Open failed : $logfile : $!";
while (<$log>) {
    ...
}
```

This approach is better because your file handle can be stored in a lexically scoped variable (rather than in a global name like `LOG`). This provides an added benefit in automatically closing the file when the lexical variable goes out of scope. Also, lexical file handles can be passed around between subroutines using a more familiar syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted an even more effortless `open`, you could do this:

```
@ARGV = 'logfile.txt';
while ( <> ) { 
    print if /\berror\b/i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`open LOG, "logfile.txt";
while (<LOG>) {
   print if /\berror\b/i;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You have an error:

```
while (<$LOG>)
```

should read

```
while (<LOG>)
```

Filehandles are not variables, so no $.

Comment: filehandles can be variables if you use lexical filehandles

Comment: +1  @jmz, you are the only one (so far) to answer the question explicitly.  Perhaps you should clarify that by "filehandle" you mean a dynamically scoped, literal identifier representing an open file.